# Entitymanager automatic update netbeans

Tags: jpa, netbeans, eclipselink, entitymanager

I have a question regarding my entity manager (eclipselink). I'Ve generated eclipselink JPA entitymanager for my project with netbeans(let netbeans generate the classes and relationships) but now I made some changes to my database tables: added some and made some relations.

So now my classes aren't valid anymore. Is there a way I can automatically let netbeans update this or do I have to change it manually

Answer (score 0):

eclipselink don't generate entities from tables but the specific plug-in does.

for net-beans users; check this link if it's helpful for you--
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53057/jpa-modeler